# Updating A List Word Counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge, counter

I'm creating a program that counts letters. I created two dictionaries that both have the same word and, because they are the same exact word, both have the same counter. I want to know how to merge the two dictionaries so that it updates the counters as well, but I consistently receive the result "NONE."

```
word = 'he'
word2 = 'he'
d1 = {}
d2 = {}

for letter in word:
    if letter in d1:
        d1[letter]+=1
    else:
        d1[letter] = 1
print(d1)

#That Outputs: {'h': 1, 'e': 1}


for letter in word2:
    if letter in d2:
        d2[letter]+=1
    else:
        d2[letter] = 1
print(d2)

#That Outputs {'h': 1, 'e': 1}



#That Outputs: None

#I want the outputs {'h': 2, 'e': 2}
```

Comment: `.update` modified the dictionary in place. Did you see what `dict` is after you can `update()`?

Comment: Note that simply `update` won't _add_ values when keys already exist, it'll replace them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate strings and use a single dictionary:

```
word1 = 'he'
word2 = 'he'

common_dict = {}
for letter in word1 + word2:
    if letter in common_dict:
        common_dict[letter] += 1
    else:
        common_dict[letter] = 1
print(common_dict)
```

Also please never use a built-in name as a variable name. In your case, you used `dict` as a variable name